# Pandas dataframe reduce row values between specific dates

Tags: python, pandas

```
datetime       JD
2000-01-01      1
2000-01-02      2
2000-01-03      3
2000-01-04      4
2000-01-05      5
2000-01-06      6
2000-01-07      7
2000-01-08      8
2000-01-09      9
```

I have the dtaaframe above, where the index is the column datetime. I would like to decrease the values in the column JD (by 1) from 5th Jan 2000 to 8th Jan 2000, using the dates (and not merely row numbers). Is there a pandas command to do this? I have been playing around with apply, but not sure how to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the index is `DatetimeIndex`, you can use this slicing notation to update the corresponding rows:

```
df.ix['2000-01-05':'2000-01-08', 'JD'] -= 1 
print df
```

If not, you can first convert the index using:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Output:

```
            JD
2000-01-01   1
2000-01-02   2
2000-01-03   3
2000-01-04   4
2000-01-05   4
2000-01-06   5
2000-01-07   6
2000-01-08   7
2000-01-09   9
```

Comment: Nice and simple, no need for apply.

Comment: ty @YS-L, can your soln. be extended to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941009/reduce-column-values-for-leap-years-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

@YS-L's solution works, but I thought I'd point out that there's no need to convert the index type. The following works as well with "native" datetime objects. For example, to select the rows you want, the following works:

```
idx = (df.index >= datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 5)) & (df.index < datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 8))
df.ix[idx, 'JD'] -= 1
```

or

```
idx = (df.index >= datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 5)) & (df.index < datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 8))
df.ix[idx, 'JD'] = df[idx].JD - 1
```

Comment: ty @Oliver, can your soln. be extended to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941009/reduce-column-values-for-leap-years-in-pandas-dataframe