# Reduce column values for leap years in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of the foll. form:

```
datetime       JD      YEAR
2000-01-01      1      2000
2000-01-02      2      2000
2000-01-03      3      2000
2000-01-04      4      2000
2000-01-05      5      2000
2000-01-06      6      2000
2000-01-07      7      2000
2000-01-08      8      2000
2000-01-09      9      2000
...
2010-12-31      365    2014
```

The JD value is the julian day i.e it starts at 1 on Jan 1st of each year (going upto 366 for leap years and 365 for others). I would like to reduce the JD value by 1, for each day starting on Feb 29th of each leap year. JD values should not be changed for non-leap years. Here is what I am doing right now:

```
def reduce_JD(row):
    if calendar.isleap(row.YEAR) & row.JD > 59:
        row.JD = row.JD - 1

    return row

def remove_leap_JD(df):
    # Reduce JD by 1 for each day following Feb 29th
    df.apply(reduce_JD, axis=1)

    return df

pdf = remove_leap_JD(pdf)
```

However, I do not see any change in JD values for leap years. What I am doing wrong?

--EDIT:
datetime is the index column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. In `reduce_JD()`, `and` should be used instead of `&`. Otherwise, due to operator precedence, the second part of the condition `df.iloc[59].JD > 59` should be bracketed. Note that:

   ```
   calendar.isleap(df.iloc[59].YEAR) & (df.iloc[59].JD > 59)
   # True
   calendar.isleap(df.iloc[59].YEAR) & df.iloc[59].JD > 59
   # False!
   ```
2. The `apply` function returns a new DataFrame instead of modifying the input in-place. Therefore, in `remove_leap_JD()`, the code should be changed to something like:

   ```
   df = df.apply(reduce_JD, axis=1)
   ```